# ¿Cómo arreglo el evento de pulsar las teclas de este juego hecho en java?

Tags: java

Aquí tengo el código del .java completo, en la clase del main:

```
package javaapplication15;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class JavaApplication15 {
    public static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> Keys = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> Blocks = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Ventana principal:
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Lienzo del juego:
        Canvas canvas1=new Canvas();
        canvas1.setVisible(true);
        canvas1.setFocusable(false);
        frame.add(canvas1);        
        // Tiempo en segundos:
        int time=0;
        // Inicialización del jugador:
        Blocks.put("tuxónX",32);
        Blocks.put("tuxónY",32);
        while(true){
            // Redimensionar el canvas:
            canvas1.setSize (frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            // Draw BG:
            Graphics g = canvas1.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g.fillRect(0,0,frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            // Draw Player:
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
            g.fillRect(Blocks.get("tuxónX"),Blocks.get("tuxónY"),32, 32);
            // Mover al jugador:
            if(Keys.get(int 37,true)){
                Blocks.put("tuxónX",Blocks.get("tuxónX")+1);
            }else if(Keys.get(int 38,true)){
                Blocks.put("tuxónX",Blocks.get("tuxónX")-1);
            }else if(Keys.get(int 39,true)){
                Blocks.put("tuxónY",Blocks.get("tuxónY")-1);
            }else if(Keys.get(int 40,true)){
                Blocks.put("tuxónY",Blocks.get("tuxónY")+1);
            }
            // Tiempo en segundos:
            time++;
            // Refrescar la ventana:
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
    }
    public static void onKeyDown(KeyEvent event) {
        Keys.put((int)event.getKeyCode(),true);
    }
    public static void onKeyUp(KeyEvent event) {
        Keys.put((int)event.getKeyCode(),false);
    }
}
```

Y aquí el error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - unexpected type
> required: value
> found:    class
> at javaapplication15.JavaApplication15.main(JavaApplication15.java:42)
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Lo que pretendo es que el cuadro se mueva por el escenario pulsando las flechas del teclado.

Comment: en tus imports no veo que hayas puesto el de InterruptedException, ese podría ser el problema

Comment: Debes agregarle el evento "addKeyListener" al frame o canvas y sobreescribir "keyPressed" y "keyReleased". Dentro de estos debes llamar a tus métodos onKeyDown y onKeyUp, para activar "true" cuando se presione o se suelte una tecla. Por otro lado, cuando obtienes un valor desde "Keys", se le debe pasar un único valor y este te devolverá true o false ya que el mapa contiene un boolean asociado: `if(Keys.get(37)) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de empezar, te propongo que quites todo tu código del **main**,y lo implementes en un método (por ejemplo "ejecutar),  esto te ahorrará un montón de dolores de cabeza, lo dejamos así:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    JavaApplication15 aplicacion = new JavaApplication15();
    aplicacion.ejecutar();
}
```

Como puedes ver, creamos un objeto de la clase **JavaApplication15** y con el llamamos al método **ejecutar** que creamos.
De paso le quitamos el **throws InterruptedException** ya que no queremos arrojar nada.

Ahora si, tu código tiene algunos problemines... vamos con el "matador".

```
if( Keys.get( int 37,true )){
    Blocks.put( "tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ) +1 );
}
else if( Keys.get( int 38,true)){
    Blocks.put("tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" )-1 );
}
else if( Keys.get( int 39,true)){
    Blocks.put("tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" )-1 );
}
else if( Keys.get( int 40,true)){
    Blocks.put("tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" )+1 );
}
```

Una colección, es como una caja, si quieres sacar algo de una caja, primero tienes que poner ese "algo" dentro, declaras **Keys = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();** y lo siguiente que pasa con este **HashMap**, es que le pides (con el método **get**) ese "algo", es obvio que no puede dar lo que no tiene, pero hay algo peor, se lo pides así:

```
Keys.get( int 37,true )
```

Esto es erróneo, seguramente se te mezcló la declaración de un método, donde se indica el **tipo** de los parámetros, como esto:

```
void mostrarParámetros( int repi1, int repi2 ) { // etc.
```

En el llamado a un método, solo se agregan las variables (o literales):

```
int valorA = 4; 
int valorB = 8;
mostrarParámetros( valorA, valorB );
```

o bien

```
mostrarParámetros( 4, 8 );
```

En poner el **int 38** en tu llamada a los métodos, es lo que hizo `crashear` a tu programa (si no fuera por eso, hubiese hecho por falta de datos en el **HashMap**).

Hay más, en realidad, no necesitas el **HashMap** llamado **Key** (al menos yo no lo veo así), lo que necesitas es un método que detecte las pulsaciones del teclado, debes agregar un "escuchador" (Listener) a tu `frame`, pero primero veamos como queda el bloque de `if`:

```
if( keyCode == 37 ) {
   Blocks.put( "tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ) - 1 );
}
else if( keyCode == 38 ) {
   Blocks.put( "tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" ) - 1 );
}
else if( keyCode == 39 ) {
   Blocks.put( "tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ) + 1 );
}
else if( keyCode == 40 ) {
   Blocks.put( "tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" ) + 1 );
}
keyCode = 0;
```

modifiqué algunos valores, ya que apretabas "flechaArriba" e iva a la derecha, etc, agregué la linea **keyCode = 0;** es para que cuando suelte la tecla, la caja se detenga (puedes quitarla).

Simplemente verificas si **keyCode** tiene un valor especificado.
Ahora veamos como agregar un escuchador.

```
   // este atributo, lo declaramos en el cuerpo de la clase, para que 
   // la clase "hija" (**KeyAdapter**) pueda leer su valor.
int keyCode = 0;

   // el escuchador dentro del método **ejecutar**.
frame.addKeyListener( new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyPressed( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
      keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
   }    
   public void keyReleased( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
      // este método no lo usaremos, pero al ser **KeyAdapter** una clase abstracta, 
      // te obliga a implementar todos sus métodos
   }
});
```

Para ir finalizando, quité los métodos **onKeyDown** y **onKeyUp**, porque no los necesitamos, y para no arrojar una excepción, puse **Thread.sleep( 20 );**, dentro de un bloque `try/catch`.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
public class JavaApplication15 {

   public static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> Keys = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
   public static HashMap<String, Integer> Blocks = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   int keyCode = 0;

   void ejecutar() {
      // Ventana principal:
      JFrame frame = new JFrame( "JFrame Example" );
      frame.setSize( 640, 480 );
      frame.setVisible( true );
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      // Lienzo del juego:
      Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
      canvas1.setVisible( true );
      canvas1.setFocusable( false );
      frame.add( canvas1 );
      frame.addKeyListener( new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyPressed( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
            keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
            System.out.println( keyCode );
         }

         public void keyReleased( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
            // este método no lo usaremos, pero al ser **KeyAdapter** una clase abstracta, 
            // te obliga a implementar todos sus métodos
         }
      } );
      // Tiempo en segundos:
      int time = 0;
      // Inicialización del jugador:
      Blocks.put( "tuxónX", 32 );
      Blocks.put( "tuxónY", 32 );
      while( true ) {
         // Redimensionar el canvas:
         canvas1.setSize( frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() );
         // Draw BG:
         Graphics g = canvas1.getGraphics();
         g.setColor( new Color( 0, 0, 0 ) );
         g.fillRect( 0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() );
         // Draw Player:
         g.setColor( new Color( 0, 255, 0 ) );
         g.fillRect( Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ), Blocks.get( "tuxónY" ), 32, 32 );
         // Mover al jugador:
         if( keyCode == 37 ) {
            Blocks.put( "tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ) - 1 );
         }
         else if( keyCode == 38 ) {
            Blocks.put( "tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" ) - 1 );
         }
         else if( keyCode == 39 ) {
            Blocks.put( "tuxónX", Blocks.get( "tuxónX" ) + 1 );
         }
         else if( keyCode == 40 ) {
            Blocks.put( "tuxónY", Blocks.get( "tuxónY" ) + 1 );
         }
         keyCode = 0;
         // Tiempo en segundos:
         time++;
         // Refrescar la ventana:
         try {
            Thread.sleep( 20 );
         }
         catch( Exception e ) {
         }
      }

   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
      JavaApplication15 aplicacion = new JavaApplication15();
      aplicacion.ejecutar();
   }
}
```

Para resolver cualquier duda que tengas, solo tienes que preguntar.